# How to save JS Date.now() in PostgreSQL?

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I tried to use PostgreSQL `timestamp` datatype, but it throws an error

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "1489849402536"
```

The schema

```
create table times (
  time   timestamp    not null,
);
```

JS code

```
`insert into times(time) values (${Date.now()})`
```

P.S. another option is to use `bigint` but it seems like an overkill.

Comment: Try casting to timestamp in your query.  IIRC it would be `${Date.now()}::tstamp`

Comment: Thanks, may I loose any data by casting?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use the [`to_timestamp()` postgres function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html):

```
`insert into times (time) values (to_timestamp(${Date.now()} / 1000.0))`
```

Comment: By way of explanation for this answer, JavaScript `Date.now()` returns the number of _milliseconds_ since the Unix Epoch (1 Jan 1970). PostgreSQL `to_timestamp(…)` converts a single argument, interpreted as the number of _seconds_ since the Unix Epoch into a PosgtreSQL timestamp. At some point, the JavaScript value needs to be divided by 1000. You could also write `to_timestamp(${Date.now()/1000})`.

Comment: Thanks didn't knew that PostgreSQL uses seconds instead of milliseconds, so sadly there will be a data loss...

Comment: To keep milliseconds, use `/ 1000.0` instead. I have fixed my answer above.

Comment: Why is the ${ } syntax needed?

Comment: It is string injection. You can write 'INSERT INTO 
 times (time) VALUES (to_timestamp(' + Date.now() /1000.0 + '))' too.    @Edward

Comment: Thanks Udi and Manngo. I been figuring out this for hours.

Comment: @AlexCraft: in reality the standard is based on seconds, only JavaScript is based on milliseconds.

Answer (score 34):

Or you can do something similar to this:

```
const time = new Date().toISOString();
```

In your query builder:

```
...
.update()
.set({column_name: time})
```

Comment: As an info `toString()` give time like this `Sat Mar 20 2021 22:02:18 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)`

Comment: for me it gives `2022-06-15T12:51:35.138Z` which is also not compatible with Postgres

Comment: this gives the time in GMT time zone

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you are using Sequelize, you can use: `sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')`.
Example:

```
await PurchaseModel.update( {purchase_date : sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') }, { where: {id: purchaseId} } );
```

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript**

```
const iso8601timestamp = new Date().toISOString(); // 2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z

let sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO times (time) VALUES (" + iso8601timestamp + ")";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

**PostgreSQL**

ISO 8601 is the recommended date format by PostgreSQL.

*NOTE*: ISO 8601 specifies the use of uppercase letter T to separate the date and time. PostgreSQL accepts that format on input, but on output it uses a space rather than T, as shown above. This is for readability and for consistency with RFC 3339 as well as some other database systems.

Input style: `1997-12-17 07:37:16-08` or `2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z` (both are accepted by PostgreSQL)
Output style: `1997-12-17 07:37:16-08`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html

**ISO 8601**

https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html