# Convert from JS timestamp to Postgresql Timestamp with time zone

Tags: javascript, postgresql-11

I have a simple `t = Date.now;` which goes to Postresql `t_time` column declared as `timestamp with time zone` via REST API.
I got the error:`date/time field value out of range`.

I ***can't*** use the answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876071/how-to-save-js-date-now-in-postgresql) as I don't write raw SQL but use ORM(Knex.Js). Calling db only to make the conversion looks like an overkill to me. Any other solution in js?

How come I can't find a convertor? Am I missing something?

***Note:*** I just need date and time as hh:mm:ss, I don't need milliseconds.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) only provides the *since EPOCH* in milliseconds.

You need an ISO date time string. To achieve that, set `t` like this:

```js
const t = new Date(Date.now()).toISOString();
console.log(t);
```

Comment: Nope! This *toISOString();* is what I was looking for. Added a hook, converted all time related data, works like magic! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it's sorted. I'll remove the bit about EPOCH then.

Comment: leave it. Maybe somebody else will need it.

Comment: `const t = new Date().toISOString()` suffices.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const getTIMESTAMPTZ = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    let offset = -date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
    const sign = (offset >= 0) ? '+' : '-';
    offset = Math.abs(offset);
    offset = (offset < 10) ? ('0' + offset) : offset;
    let TIMESTAMPTZ = date.toISOString();
    TIMESTAMPTZ = TIMESTAMPTZ.replace('T', ' ');
    TIMESTAMPTZ = TIMESTAMPTZ.replace('Z', `000${sign}${offset}`);
    return TIMESTAMPTZ;
};
console.log(' Example from PostgreSQL: ' + '2023-05-28 18:52:17.182883-07');
console.log('Output of getTIMESTAMPTZ: ' + getTIMESTAMPTZ());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const t = Date.now().toString();
console.log(Date.now(), t);
const v = new Date(Number(t))
console.log(v);
```